# merge file text with file name

Tags: cat

I have two text files. The first "file1.txt"  has content:

```
Apple
Orange
Banana
```

while the second file "file2.txt" has content:

```
monday
tuesday
wednesday
```

I want to combine them into one file and its output is:

```
Apple       File1.txt
Orange      File1.txt
Banana      File1.txt
monday      File2.txt
tuesday     File2.txt
wednesday   File2.txt
```

Answer (score 14):

That's quite trivial with `awk`:

```
$ awk '{print $0,FILENAME}' File*.txt
Apple File1.txt
Orange File1.txt
Banana File1.txt
monday File2.txt
tuesday File2.txt
wednesday File2.txt
```

If you want a tab rather than a space between the input line and the filename, add `-v OFS='\t'` to the command-line to set the Output Field Separator (OFS):

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{print $0,FILENAME}' File*.txt
```

or use:

```
awk '{print $0 "\t" FILENAME}' File*.txt
```

That's assuming file names don't contain `=` characters. If you can't guarantee that the filenames won't contain `=` characters, you can change that to:

```
awk '{print $0 "\t" substr(FILENAME, 3)}' ./File*.txt
```

Though with GNU `awk` at least, you'd then get warnings if the name of the file contained bytes not forming valid characters (which you could work around by fixing the locale to `C` (with `LC_ALL=C awk...`) though that would also have the side effect of potentially changing  the language of other error messages if any).

Comment: it's kind of annoying that gawk doesn't understand `--` as most other GNU programs do or have some other way of stopping it from interpreting `=` in a filename as`var=value`.

Comment: `gawk` does understand `--` as end-of-options like all POSIX awk implementations (`awk -- 'code' args`) but it doesn't stop arguments with `=` from being treated as variable assignments. It has `awk -E file.awk args` for that though (so you can do `gawk -e 'code' -E /dev/null other args x=y.txt File*.txt...`). But that's gawk-specific.

Answer (score 3):

With `perl`:

```
perl -lpe '$_ .= "\t$ARGV"' File*.txt
```

(note that it's fine with a glob like `File*.txt` but [could be dangerous with different ones](/q/170013)).

Answer (score 2):

For interactive use on the command line, one of the easiest things to type is

```
grep . File*.txt
```

Since the regex `.` matches any character, every non-empty line of every file will match, and be printed with the filename as a prefix.

It's great for use-cases like checking some kernel settings that are stored with one setting per file:

```
$ grep . /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/*
/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag:[always] defer defer+madvise madvise never
/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled:[always] madvise never
/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/hpage_pmd_size:2097152
grep: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/khugepaged: Is a directory
/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/shmem_enabled:always [within_size] advise never deny force
/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/use_zero_page:1
```

Comment: See `grep -H . File*.txt` with GNU `grep` or `grep . /dev/null File*.txt` with other finds if the glob may expand to only one file (and `grep '^' File*.txt` to print empty lines as well).